# UML Sequence Diagram help needed

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I am currently stuck with creating a UML sequence diagram. The diagram will only have one Actor which is staff, staff needs to instate a member once they are informed by the member and this goes through the database as well.

1 actor- Staff

Classes- Library information system- Interface
         Member
         Database

Please could you help me with the sequence diagram as I am currently stuck.

Staff needs to add member to library system once the member has informed the staff to add him or her to to the library system.

Then this needs to go to the database which send a return message to the staff to tell them that the member has been added.

Only staff is talking to the system and nobody.

Comment: What did you draw already? (_nothing_ is not sufficient answer)

Comment: I cant post a pic as my reputation is not high. So far i have staff, library IS, member and database. only staff is inside the usecase nobody else.

Comment: Actually I don't understand what you mean by "staff needs to instate a member". I guess you mean that the actor acts as member which is a specialized staff.

Comment: Actor is only staff and not member. Staff only interacts with the system not member. member needs to inform staff if they want to to be added to the system.

Comment: @SamJones You must at describing with as much detail. By that what you mention us little can be done. We are not next to you to see what you have.

Comment: Staff needs to add member to library system once the member has informed the staff to add him or her to to the library system.

Then this needs to go to the database which send a return message to the staff to tell them that the member has been added.

Only staff is talking to the system and nobody

Answer (score 0):

Following [websequencediagrams.com script](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/?lz=dGl0bGUgSSBhbSBjdXJyZW50bHkgc3R1Y2sKCnBhcnRpY2lwYW50IE1lbWJlcgAGDVN0YWZmABgNSW50ZXJmYWNlACgHIERhdGFiYXNlAD4NTGlicmFyeSBJbmZvcm1hdGlvbiBTeXN0ZW0KCgBhBi0-AFcFOiBpAB4FCgBlBS0-AEYZOiBpbnN0YW50aWF0ZQoAbRktLT4ATwoAJwlkLCB3aGF0ZXZlciBpdCBtZWFucwBqCACBcAYAUg0oZCkKAIEoGi0-AIFEGjogd2h5IHdhcyBJIGJvcm4_&s=napkin) describes what you gave us

[image]

See also:

- [uml-diagrams.org: Sequence Diagrams Reference](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-reference.html)

---

Designing or implementing software with lousy description of requirements (user stories, use cases) is a waste of time and money on all sides, don't learn it...

> [How Projects Really Work - http://www.projectcartoon.com](http://www.projectcartoon.com/cartoon/1)
>
> [image]
>
> (orange short path drawn by me)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is so simple, I really do not understand how you're not able to.

What you need to do is to send a message from Member to Staff. Then from the Staff to the system. Inside the System send the order to keep the database.
Responses are then sent from the system to Staff and finally from the staff member.

It would be something like:

1. Member -> RequestAccess(DataOfMember) -> Staff
2. Staff -> Register(DataofMember) -> System

Note: You can use the stereotype System (remember to use the < and >) to represent the system as a whole. This allows abstracting the problem and not have to deal with specific classes that form the system.

3. System -> InsertIntoDB -> System

This is a message to itself.

4. <> -> OperationComplete -> Staff
5. Staff -> AccessAccepted -> Member

Steps 4 and 5 are the returns.

With all this should be enough to make you understand.
Now if you you should tread more carefully and need to represent the classes involved in the system must describe the Domain Model.

---

EDIT:
Attached an image for my example. Not so different than you have before.

[image: Diagram secuence]

Comment: UML Sequence Diagram is a picture. Can you turn your long text imagination exercise into picture?

Comment: Delphius could you possibility send me an image of this please.

Comment: In a while. I was pretty busy, my apologies.

Comment: Hi That's good, staff is not a object as its the actor who interacts with the system. I want it like Staff=Actor then system, staff and database.

Comment: WhiteStarUML not add an actor, not least in the version I have. This is an example. The databases are not placed in the sequence diagram. Instead it is desirable to place the object that acts as a cover of the database; as a persistence engine for example.

Comment: Delphius could you possibility help me with a state machine diagram. The classes which I have are staff, member, item, borrow, return, overdue and fine class. I wanted to create a state diagram for this but however I am currently struggling. Please advise ?.

Comment: 1. What you're asking out of topic for this question. You must do start a new post with this question. 2. What you are suggesting seems to me more like a class diagram and not a state diagram. I suggest you put more attention to the theory of UML. 3. Private Help'm not in a position to give, it is assumed that StackOverflow is collaborative and public.